# Edit '%s has been added to your cart' text without removing 'view cart' button

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I've been trying to edit the '%s has been added to your cart' text,
not really experienced in coding..
so I tried a few different codes I found online,
but they all seem to remove the 'view cart' button, which I want it to stay.

Is there a way to edit the message without removing the button?

This is the code I'm using:

```
/**
* @snippet       Edit "has been added to your cart" message
* @how-to        Get CustomizeWoo.com FREE
* @author        Rodolfo Melogli
* @compatible    WC 5
* @donate $9     https://businessbloomer.com/bloomer-armada/
*/
 
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', 'bbloomer_custom_add_to_cart_message' );
 
function bbloomer_custom_add_to_cart_message() {
   $message = 'Nicely done!' ;
   return $message;
}
```

Thanks in advance!
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the HTML of the button in the string you return from the filter. For example:

```php
add_filter( 'wc_add_to_cart_message_html', function ( $message ) {

    $text = 'Product added to your cart.';

    return sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" tabindex="1" class="button wc-forward">%s</a> %s',
        esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ),
        esc_html__( 'View cart', 'woocommerce' ),
        esc_html( $text )
    );

} );
```

Replace "Product added to your cart." with your desired text.